# Please create mouse hover event handler for response acceptance button

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

As I have wrote in a comment, if there would be mouse hover event handler on acceptance button the acceptance button would become more intuitive (as I didn't know that it was existing) so the UX also would be better.

Comment: What would that handler do? There already is a tooltip (shown in the [faq] screenshots).

Answer (score 3):

> ...button the acceptance button would become more intuitive...

It is *intuitive* considering that the rest of the site does not have hover-effects either *(except third-party stuff like the editor and the new user-card)*.

> (as i didn't know that it was existing)

[image: I have freehandcircled it for you.]

It's there...it's right there...